# display content on highcharts Xaxis and Yaxis title in form of subscript and superscript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using a highcharts for my application to display mathmatical calculation and electical terminology so I need to display elctrical term on highcharts  Xaxis title and Yaxis title on form of superscript and subscript I have tried no of ways but  yet I don't get any soln  html sub and sup tags are not working there please give me any proper solution.

Comment: have you tried something like explained here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.title.text

Comment: It looks like you can do something like this: `<sup>3</sup>` to have a cubed number / variable in the superscript position, same thing with `<sub>0</sub>` for subscripting things.

Answer (score 11):

Consider using [**`useHTML` property**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title.useHTML):

```
...
//some options
title: {
   useHTML: true,
   text: "<sub>sub</sub>normal<sup>sup</sup>"
}
//other options
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use useHTML property at chart title, axis labels, legend labels and data labels -

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        credits : {
            enabled : false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart Title<sup>1</sup>',
            useHTML : true,
        },
        xAxis: {
   categories: [ 'label1','label2','label3<sup>4</sup>','label4'],
            title:{
                enabled: false
            },      
            labels: {
                useHTML : true,
                title: {
                    enabled: false
                }         
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                useHTML : true,
                formatter:function(){
                    if(this.value != 10){
                        return this.value;
                    }else{
                        return this.value + '<sup> 2</sup>';
                    }     
                }        
            }      
        },
        legend: {
            useHTML : true,
            borderWidth: 0,
            labelFormatter:function(){
                if(this.name != 'legend1'){
                    return this.name;
                }else{
                    return this.name + '<sup> 5</sup>';
                }     
            } 
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML : true,
                    y:-1,
                    formatter:function(){
                        if(this.y != 0){
                            if(this.y > 8 && this.y < 10){
                                return this.y + '<sup> 3</sup>';
                            }else{
                                return this.y;
                            }

                        }else{
                            return null;
                        }     
                    }    
                }      
            }   
        },  
        series: [{ 
            data: [{ 
                y: 14.913
            }, { 
                y: 8.281
            }, { 
                y: 3.592
            }, { 
                y: 3.017
            }], 
            showInLegend: false,
        },{
            name: 'legend1',
            color: 'rgb(14,178,89)'      
        },{
            name: 'legend2',
            color: 'rgb(100,100,9)'      
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```